# Can't set up subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, subdomain

I'm running Apache on Ubuntu and I'm trying to set up a subdomain on my website. I've set up many subdomains in the past and I'm sure that I'm configuring Apache correctly but, with this new hosting company I'm using, I can't set up any subdomains on my domain.

Could it be that the host doesn't have their DNS servers configured to allow wildcard subdomains? When I enter asdf.mydomain.com on my MediaTemple site, I just get the front page for mydomain.com, but when I enter asdf.myotherdomain.com, I get server not found.

That's the only thing I can think of. I want to make sure I have my ducks in a row before I go ask them to look into the problem for me, so does it sound like that's probably the issue or could it be something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try pinging asdf.myotherdomain.com to see if it resolves, and if it resolves to the same IP as a ping myotherdomain.com.  If you can't ping your subdomain the answer is with the DNS.

Comment: I can't ping the subdomain at all, so I guess it's a DNS problem.

Comment: IF the subdomain won't resolve, then you have to be missing the wildcard in your DNS for the domain.